# Is there a database diagram design for nosql databases like the entity relationship diagram for sql databases?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, entity-relationship

I'm building the database in MongoDB for my project. When we design a sql database we have entity relationship diagram. what diagrams should we use for nosql database designing. Are we allowed to use er diagrams in nosql as well even though few of the concepts differ?

Comment: This is a starting point - MongoDB docs for [Data Models](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/data-modeling/). Broadly, the data relationships are similar to sql databases (1:1, 1:N and N:N), but the way you design your database is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Moon Modeler](https://www.datensen.com) for drawing MongoDB schema diagram, similar to entity relationship diagrams.